# Какие форматы изображений поддерживаются QImage-м в QT?

Tags: qt, qimage

Здравствуйте!
Кто знает какие форматы изображений изображений поддерживаются QImage-м?
В сети искал, что-то ничего такого нет(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плохо искали:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats